# Database creation failed: error: syntax error at or near ";"

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I am working on a project In which user database is created when he successfully signs Up.On the frontend form user inputs the size of the database. Now on the backend I have a createDatabase function which creates database for the user and sets size of database as per the size given by user. Here is the code of my function;

```
exports.createAdminDatabase = async (user , spaceneeded) => {
  try {
    
    const { id, name } = user;
    const uniqueDbName = `${name}_${id}`;
    const megabytes = spaceneeded; 
    const bytes = megabytes * 1024 * 1024; // Convert MB to bytes

    // Creating the new database
    await db.none(`CREATE DATABASE $1:name;`, [uniqueDbName]);

    // Alter the new database to set the size
    await db.none(`ALTER DATABASE $1:name SIZE $2:raw;`, [uniqueDbName, `${bytes}B`]);

    // Switching to the newly created database
    const newDb = pgp({ ...connection, database: uniqueDbName });

    // Creating the 'cars' table within the new database
    await newDb.none(`
      CREATE TABLE cars (
        carName TEXT,
        carModel TEXT,
        carCc INT
      );
    `);

    // Updating the db_created value for the admin to true
    user.db_created = true;
    await user.save();
 return uniqueDbName; 
  } 
  catch (error) {
    // Handle errors, e.g., database or table creation failure
    console.error('Database creation failed:', error);
    throw new Error('Database creation failed');
  } finally {
    // Release the database connection
    pgp.end();
  }
};
```

Now I am getting this error on backend terminal when I submit the form;

```
Database creation failed: error: syntax error at or near ";"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (E:\Job Tasks\LoginSignupApp\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (E:\Job Tasks\LoginSignupApp\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (E:\Job Tasks\LoginSignupApp\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Job Tasks\LoginSignupApp\Backend\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 90,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '47',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1180',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror',
  query: 'ALTER DATABASE "bytesSpace_75" SIZE 104857600B;',
  params: undefined
}
 Error: Database creation failed
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no `size` clause in [`alter database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html) and `104857600B` is not a valid literal of any kind, in any version.
Different versions parse this differently, which is why they complain at different stages:

[15+](https://dbfiddle.uk/y1DosXQn) at the literal:

> ```
> ERROR:  trailing junk after numeric literal at or near "104857600B"
> LINE 1: alter database "template1" size 104857600B;
>                                         ^
> ```

[9.5-14](https://dbfiddle.uk/j92kDlVc) at the semicolon - in these versions [`104857600B` works as `104857600::int AS "b"`](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tj97sOu8) which confuses the parser in a different way:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
> LINE 1: alter database "template1" size 104857600B;
>                                                   ^
> ```

Even if you fix the literal, this still makes no sense to PostgreSQL:

```
alter database "template1" size 104857600;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  option "size" not recognized
> LINE 1: alter database "template1" size 104857600;
>                                    ^
> ```

[9.4](https://dbfiddle.uk/_-CDyfQe) complains about it regardless of whether the literal is valid, even though it would potentially accept it as `104857600::int AS "b"` elsewhere:

```
alter database "template1" size 104857600B;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "size"
> LINE 1: alter database "template1" size 104857600B;
>                                    ^
> ```